# how do i apply $match, $group and $sum in single query using mongoose/mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am trying to find solution with my basic knowledge of MongoDB.

I have data like below

```
{
 _id: 45556,
 "name": "John",
 "gender": "male",
 "lunch_preference":[
             {"outlet":"KFC", "day":"monday", "spent":300},
             {"outlet":"Mc", "day":"friday", "spent":250},
             {"outlet":"dominos", "day":"sunday", "spent":400}
  ]
}

{
 _id: ab123,
 "name": "Peter",
 "gender": "male",
 "lunch_preference":[
             {"outlet":"dominos", "day":"tuesday", "spent":150},
             { "outlet":"Mc", "day":"wednesday", "spent":350},
             {"outlet":"dominos", "day":"sunday", "spent":300}
 ]
}
```

Here i am filtering the data using `$match` 
My query for filtering:

```
db.lunch.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$lunch_preference"}, {$match: {"lunch_preference.outlet": "dominos"}},{$match: {"lunch_preference.day": "sunday"}}])
```

This query working fine!
Now I want to calculate(sum of spendings) the spendings of above filtered data so i applied like below.

```
db.lunch.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$lunch_preference"}, {$match: {"lunch_preference.outlet": "dominos"}}, {$match: {"lunch_preference.day": "sunday"}}, { $group: { "_id": "$lunch_preference.outlet", totalAmount: { "$sum": "$lunch_preference.spent"}} }])
```

Result is:

```
{ "_id" : "dominos", "totalAmount" : 0 }
```

it is showing total amount zero, help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You close to solution but you missed following so below query will solve your problem

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
    "$unwind": "$lunch_preference"
}, {
    "$match": {
        "lunch_preference.outlet": "dominos",
        "lunch_preference.day": "sunday"
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$lunch_preference.outlet",
        "total": {
            "$sum": "$lunch_preference.spent"
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: it is showing same result, as i got before.  { "_id" : "dominos", "total" : 0 }

Comment: @SettiMahesh it to difficult because as per your given documents above query shows results as well as your query also shows the correct results.

Comment: problem solved, i define spent schema as string. i changed now. it is working fine